# Access 2010 upsize to Azure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, azure, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to upsize Access 2010 backend database to Azure using the Access Upsize Wizard.  I have no problem doing this locally to my own SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Express.  When I try to upsize to Azure I first get the following error...

Could not find stored procedure xp_msver

Then get error...

The Upsizing Wizard does not work with the version of Microsoft SQL Server to which your Access project is connected.  See the Microsoft Office Update Web site for the latest information and downloads.

I assume this last error is solely due to the first error.  Is it not possible to upsize to Azure?

UPDATE: I tried to use SQL Server Management Studio Export/Import wizard to export from my local SQL Server 2008 R2 to Azure.  Thought at first it may work, but then got error on a table "Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL server."

I could possibly modify the initial tables, but there are probably 100 tables and figure this could take a lot of effort without any guarantee.

Really, I am just trying to upsize to any cloud SQL Server. Have tried a couple of others and have run into the problem that they do not provide "dbo" rights, which Access upsize requires.  I think DiscountASP.net does,  but a little expensive when you have to pay per database and I have 3 (small ones).

Comment: Have you tried using the [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh302874%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: I have considered it, but from what I understand it is more work to upsize using this, plus I already have it working using a local sql server, so wish to stay with this strategy. The cloud sql server is only temporary, it will be installed on the customer premises using sql server.  Just do not have access to this yet and want to have an early version available for testing.  So, open to other cloud sql servers that provide DBO rights if Azure doesn't work out.

Comment: I read another blog that specified it was not possible to upsize Access to Azure.  I created a Discount asp.net account and was able to upsize without any problem, the tables were all "dbo" and no errors.  Just so expensive since I would have to buy a new database for each of the 3 databases ( at $10/month each ). Is only short term, so this may be the solution

Comment: Thanks for the update. Re: "not possible to upsize Access to Azure", certainly the SSMA documentation in the above link talks specifically about moving and linking Access data to Azure but I have not yet done it myself.

Comment: Gord, sorry I should have been more clear.  Yes, it probably is possible to upsize using SSMA, but I was talking specifically about using the Access built-in Upsizing wizard.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. They've removed the built-in upsizing wizard from Access 2013 so I guess that SSMA is "the way of the future".